# Use Socket for received File in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I read the msdn tutorial for using socket with Windows phone. ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket(v=VS.96).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket%28v=VS.96%29.aspx)) I arrived to connect me to the server.

This, return me an response 200 ( OK response ) =>

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 16 Apr 2012 12:45:46 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.9 (Debian) PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny13 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8g
Last-Modified: Tue, 08 Aug 2006 14:12:09 GMT
ETag: "129a2e5-100000-41a822e23a040"
Accept-Ranges: byte
```

But I don't know what to do next...

I connect me to the server, I sent this a "GET Message" for download a file

```
"GET /dwn/file.txt HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:myHost.com\r\n\r\n"
```

and After the response ? I have to do what?

If you know a tutorial, sample, or just explication, I would thank you greatly!

this my function =>

```
private void ProcessReceive(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
        {

            response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Buffer, e.Offset, e.BytesTransferred);
            response = response.Trim('\0');

           // show the response server value. 
            Debug.WriteLine(response.ToString());


            // Data has now been sent and received from the server. 
            // Disconnect from the server
            socket = e.UserToken as Socket;
            socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send);
            socket.Close();
            clientDone.Set();
        }
        else
        {
            // show error in the debugger.
            response = e.SocketError.ToString();
            Debug.WriteLine(response);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or something like that ?

If it's just for experiencing, you should know that this is not a trivial task. Here are some hints:

- You will probably **not** receive the whole HTTP response header + body in one "Receive" call. Remember, a TCP socket is a stream.
- HTTP Headers are encoded in 7 bit ASCII, not UTF8.
- HTTP Entity (well, body) encoding depends on headers, and decoding it can be tricky.

Have fun !

**Edit**

Clarifications (point #1):

```
        // Data has now been sent and received from the server. 
        // Disconnect from the server
        socket = e.UserToken as Socket;
        socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send);
        socket.Close();
```

Why do you shutdown and close the socket now? The response body follows the header in the stream. As I said, there is probably more bytes waiting to be received from the server. Continue to call "receive" until either:

- There is no more bytes to read (socket is closed by the server)
- You are sure you've read the whole response body (see "Content-Length" or "Transfer-Encoding" headers)

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I use sockets for received time between different request (send server, response server, etc...) , I know I don't received the whole HTTP response in one "receive" call, and, precisely, do you know what I need to send the server to send me back a data stream corresponding to the file that I want to download?

Comment: Yes, Thank you very very mutch, it was the problem, I understand now!! thank you!!